# Unable to dual boot ubuntu 16.04 with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

I selected the option of running Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10. But the problem I am facing right now is that I am unable to use Windows. When I start my PC there is no option of using Windows 10.

Comment: This link may help https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Was there space for Ubuntu before you installed it, or did the install resize the partition first?  If you have space for ubuntu, it should install it, then as part of the grub setup, detect the windows install and add it to the menu.

You should be able to update the grub menu with the command [see below] it might put the option back in for you.

```
sudo update-grub
```